# Ruby: Unique array of hashes with respecting the highest version

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to create a new array of hashes with unique values and with respecting the highest version of repeated hashes.
The hash looks like the following:

```
old_hash = [
{"dependency"=>"websocket", "version"=>"2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo1"},
{"dependency"=>"rails", "version"=>"6.2.0", "repo"=>"repo2"},
{"dependency"=>"httparty", "version"=>"6.0.3.5", "repo"=>"repo2"},
{"dependency"=>"httparty", "version"=>"6.1.0.2", "repo"=>"repo2"},
{"dependency"=>"httparty", "version"=>"6.1.3.2", "repo"=>"repo2"},
{"dependency"=>"rails", "version"=>"6.1.0", "repo"=>"repo3"},
{"dependency"=>"metasploit", "version"=>"2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo3"}
]
```

As you can see, the third, fourth, and fifth hash has the same value of key `dependency` which is `httparty` and also `repo` which is `repo2`, but the fifth hash has the highest version of these three. Therefore, I'd like to create a unique hash that has the first, second, fifth, sixth, and seventh hash. So the result I'm trying to have should look like this:

```
unique_hash = [
{"dependency"=>"websocket", "version"=>"2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo1"},
{"dependency"=>"rails", "version"=>"6.2.0", "repo"=>"repo2"},
{"dependency"=>"httparty", "version"=>"6.1.3.2", "repo"=>"repo2"},
{"dependency"=>"rails", "version"=>"6.1.0", "repo"=>"repo3"},
{"dependency"=>"metasploit", "version"=>"2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo3"}
]
```

Regarding the version comparison, I'm thinking of using this method to compare them right:

```
def version_greater? (version1, version2)
  Gem::Version.new(version1) > Gem::Version.new(version2)
end
```

which returns `true` in case version1 is greater than version2.

I would appreciate any suggestions that helps to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe a list of hashes is not the correct data structure to use here. I would consider using a hash of hashes instead.

Comment: It's confusing to use `Version` when you are comparing scores even though the logic here is the same. I suggest writing a function yourself with a name that makes more sense for this context.

Comment: I've edited the question =)

Comment: ok, the name change to version makes sense now. The naming and comparison is a minor detail of the question, though. As my first comment states, array is the wrong data structure for solving this problem.

Comment: And what did you try with `group_by` and `uniq`? Show some code and explain what happens when you run it.

Comment: Why is a hash of hashes is a better way to solve this problem? (sorry I'm still new to Ruby)
I wanted to use an array of hashes because I'll have to transform it to YAML format using `.to_yml`

Comment: The version numbers differ in form but for `"dependency"=>"httparty"` the form of the three version numbers is the same: `"d.d.d.d"`, where `d` represents a digit, and those three hashes are ordered by increasing version number. Is that always the case? Also are hashes having the same value for `"dependency"` necessarily contiguous, as they are in the example?

Comment: And what about `repo`. Is repo unique to each dependency or can `httparty` for example suddenly also appear in `repo4` for example. And if so, what do you want to happen then?

Comment: `Gem::Version` defines the spaceship operator `<=>` and includes `Comparable` so you can use. `old_hash.group_by {|h| h["dependency"]}.map {|_,v| v.max_by {|h| Gem::Version.new(h["version"])}}` this will group by the name an then return an `Array` of the max version for each group

Comment: @CarySwoveland the value of `"version"` can also be 3 digits, depending on the dependency. Regarding increasing version number, unfortunately it's not always the case, as sometimes the maximum version can be found in the middle. Regarding `"dependency"`, they are almost every time located contiguously in the array of hashes.

Comment: @Casper The exact case you've mentioned happened when I tried the solution of  
@engineersmnky , because for example dependency `rails` can also be found in two repos or more. Therefore, I need to include both, in case they weren't in the same `repo`. I've edited the question again to be more precise :)
Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @engineersmnky Many thanks! Your solution is functioning. However, one small problem occurs. I've updated the old_hash in the Q to include another rails gem in repo3. In this case, the 2nd rails dependency isn't going to be included in the returned values! The returned values were:
`{"dependency"=>"websocket", "version"=>"2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo1"} {"dependency"=>"rails", "version"=>"6.2.0", "repo"=>"repo2"} {"dependency"=>"httparty", "version"=>"6.1.3.2", "repo"=>"repo2"} {"dependency"=>"metasploit", "version"=>"2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo3"}`
Can we some how edit your solution to solve this case?

Comment: Just change the grouping to `group_by {|h| h.values_at("dependency","repo") }`

Comment: @engineersmnky it functioned like magic! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by using:

```
old_hash.group_by {|h| h.values_at("dependency","repo")}.map {|_,v| v.max_by {|h| Gem::Version.new(h["version"])}}
```

Thanks to @engineersmnky.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that takes a block (here `{ |_,o,n| n["version"] > o["version"] ? n : o }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
old_hash = [
  {"dependency"=>"websocket",  "version"=>"2.8.0",   "repo"=>"repo1"},
  {"dependency"=>"rails",      "version"=>"6.2.0",   "repo"=>"repo2"},
  {"dependency"=>"httparty",   "version"=>"6.0.3.5", "repo"=>"repo2"},
  {"dependency"=>"httparty",   "version"=>"6.1.0.2", "repo"=>"repo2"},
  {"dependency"=>"httparty",   "version"=>"6.1.3.2", "repo"=>"repo2"},
  {"dependency"=>"rails",      "version"=>"6.1.0",   "repo"=>"repo3"},
  {"dependency"=>"metasploit", "version"=>"2.8.0",   "repo"=>"repo3"},
  {"dependency"=>"rails",      "version"=>"6.1.9",   "repo"=>"repo2"}
]
```

Note that I've added a hash to `old_hash` shown in the question. (Incidentally, "old_hash" is perhaps not the best name for an array.)

```
old_hash.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update([g["dependency"],g["repo"]]=>g) do |_,o,n|
    n["version"] > o["version"] ? n : o
  end
end.values
  #=> [{"dependency"=>"websocket",  "version"=>"2.8.0",   "repo"=>"repo1"},
  #    {"dependency"=>"rails",      "version"=>"6.2.0",   "repo"=>"repo2"},
  #    {"dependency"=>"httparty",   "version"=>"6.1.3.2", "repo"=>"repo2"},
  #    {"dependency"=>"rails",      "version"=>"6.1.0",   "repo"=>"repo3"},  
  #    {"dependency"=>"metasploit", "version"=>"2.8.0",   "repo"=>"repo3"}]
```

---

The receiver of `values` can be seen to be the following.

```
  {["websocket", "repo1"] =>{"dependency"=>"websocket",  "version"=>  "2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo1"},
   ["rails", "repo2"]     =>{"dependency"=>"rails",      "version"=>  "6.2.0", "repo"=>"repo2"},
   ["httparty", "repo2"]  =>{"dependency"=>"httparty",   "version"=>"6.1.3.2", "repo"=>"repo2"},
   ["rails", "repo3"]     =>{"dependency"=>"rails",      "version"=>  "6.1.0", "repo"=>"repo3"},
   ["metasploit", "repo3"]=>{"dependency"=>"metasploit", "version"=>  "2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo3"}}
```

Consult the doc for descriptions of the three block variables: `_` (the common key, here an underscore to signal that it is not used in the block calculation), `o`, the value of the common key in the hash being constructed (think "old"), and `n`, the value of the common key in the hash being merged (think "new").

Answer (score 1):

## Sort By Semantic Version, Then by Select by Gem Name

The easiest and most readable (but not necessarily shortest or fastest) way to sort your items that I can think of is:

```rb
sorted_array = old_hash.sort_by { Gem::Version.new _1["version"] }
gems = old_hash.map { _1["dependency"] }.uniq.sort
gems.map { |gem| sorted_array.select { _1["dependency"] == gem }.last }
```

In Ruby 3.0.2, this yields:

```rb
[{"dependency"=>"httparty", "version"=>"6.1.3.2", "repo"=>"repo2"},
 {"dependency"=>"metasploit", "version"=>"2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo3"},
 {"dependency"=>"rails", "version"=>"6.2.0", "repo"=>"repo2"},
 {"dependency"=>"websocket", "version"=>"2.8.0", "repo"=>"repo1"}]
```

Basically, you sort your Array of Hashes by the semantic version, and then rely on your Array's sorted order and the fact that the last Hash for each gem "wins" (because of the duplicate `dependency` keys) to remove older items.

As a bonus, the gem names also appear in sorted order in your new Array. This makes it a bit easier to visually scan through them, especially as the list gets longer.